# Django ordered sequence model design

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm currently creating a database of techniques for a particular sport. In this particular sport there is a set of unique component movements (`Component`) and these combine together to make different moves (`Move`).

The order in which the components happens matters. For example we might have 3 components `A`, `B` and `C` then the move defined by A -> B -> C is distinct from A -> C -> B. As you can see there are many more moves than components. At some point in time it will be important to be able to search for `Move`s based on which `Components` are present in the different `Move`s.

So I initially was thinking that I would make a class `Component` and a class `Move` with a skeleton structure similar to:

```
class Component(models.Model):
    """Defines a unique component movement"""
    name = model.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Move(models.Model):
    """Define a move as a sequence of Components in the order in which they happen"""
    name = model.CharField(max_length=40)
    component_sequence = #what should I do here?
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now my question is what is the best way to implement `component_sequence` in a Django model? Initially I was thinking that I might be able to somehow store a csv list of the primary keys for the `Component` objects but this seems nasty so I was wondering if there's some better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a M2M model that connects `Move` to `Component`, and add an ordinal field. Create a unique index across all three.